# Interop word dynamic table creation

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to export Dataset Tables to Word. I have tried a solution using Interop Word. Here I'm facing a problem,

I need to Place the tables in the word document with a series of space, my problem I cant able to create a new table each table on the Dataset.

Here is my code,

```
    private void Exporttoword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet Ds = objMB.ExeQueryStrRetDsBL("SP_PreviewSeries" + cbMatches.SelectedValue, 1);
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application objWord;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document objDoc;
            objWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            objWord.Visible = true;
            objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            for (var w = 0; w < Ds.Tables.Count; w++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table objTable;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wrdRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
                objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, Convert.ToInt32(Ds.Tables[w].Rows.Count), Convert.ToInt32(Ds.Tables[w].Columns.Count), ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                objTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3;
                for (var i = 0; i < Ds.Tables[w].Rows.Count; i++)
                    for (var j = 0; j < Ds.Tables[w].Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        objTable.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Range.Text = Ds.Tables[w].Rows[i][j].ToString();
                        objTable.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Range.Borders.Enable = 1;
                    }
                objTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
                objTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Italic = 1;
            }
            this.Close();
            string fp = @"D:\Practice\test.docx";
            objDoc.SaveAs2(fp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will use the bookmark out of the loop to get the initial position and then inserting tables in loop. By the way, thank you to rework your question (what is the output obtained with this code ? How does it differ from the expected behavior, Are some exception throw ? Does it work for one table ?)

Comment: It does not throws any error. All tables are binding in a single table. That's the problem. Please help me solve this..

Comment: Insert a paragraph after each table (try to reproduce by hand on Word Application what your code are doing, you will spot the issue about inserting table juste after another table).

Comment: Thank you very much @Marco. Your suggestion solved my problem. Please post your answer.Thanks once again.

Comment: While execution on my program after a series of tables I'm getting this error.  "the number must be between 1 and 32767". Please respond me if you aware of this problem @MarcoGuignard

Comment: No idea about this one, I know there is a limitation on 32767 for list numbering maybe it could come from an auto list creation on your data ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcoGuignard. I solved my problem that's only because of my Dataset and thank again for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a Paragraph like Word inside your for loop.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph;
```

and at the end of for loop

```
 paragraph = objDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
```

This solution works fine for me. Try this.